# Is the Godel sentence considered true intuitionistically?

Tags: incompleteness, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In classical logic, Godel shows that there are true statements undecidable for arithmetic, and consequently, that truth goes beyond a system of axioms ability for proof. My question is, given that intuitionists hold that a true statement is just one we have constructed in a given language, and given that the incompleteness theorems hold in intuitionistic logic, can the intuitionist agree that the Godel sentence for their logic is true?

Obviously, the Godel sentence cannot be constructively proven and so they cannot hold it to be true in that sense, but our proof that it is indeed true is metatheoretical, so I'm struggling to see whether they are able to agree that it is true but unprovable, or whether they must regard it undetermined.

Thanks.

Comment: Personal pet peeve: I quibble with the statement that "our intuition that it is indeed true is not a mathematical argument." It *is* a mathematical argument, just formulated in a different system. For example, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves the Godel sentence for $\mathsf{PA}$. Indeed, Godel's theorem properly formulated says *(something like)* "*If* $T$ is a consistent computably axiomatized theory interpreting Robinson arithmetic, *then* $T\not\vdash G_T$" - and as such **is provable in $\mathsf{PA}$** or indeed much less. Godel isn't mysterious unless one is careless with what is being proved where.

Comment: Just reading your question I am not sure whether this is clear: "True" in this context means the Gödel sentence $G$ holds in the standard model i.e. $\mathbb{N} \vDash G$. And if you grant that $\mathbb{N}$ is an intuitionistic standard model of PA then the truth of $G$ should go through intuitionistically.

Comment: What does "truth" mean?  Plenty of people reject the notion of "standard models" entirely, so the answer to this depends almost entirely on whom you ask.  From my perspective, truth is model-relative and the question makes no sense...

Comment: More substantively, I think "given that intuitionists hold that a true statement is just one we can construct in a given language" is phrased dangerously imprecisely. It's not that the statement should be constructible, but that a "witness" to its truth should be.

Comment: Tried to improve the imprecise phrasing. @user3716267 since this question is about a specific perspective - intuitionism - truth is defined syntactically.

Comment: To elaborate on what Noah said, it is a mistake to think that intuitionists only consider formal proofs in a particular system to be witnesses to truth. Brouwer was pretty famously anti-formalism. Rather, formal proofs _correspond_ to witnesses. Excluded middle fails because there is no universal means of obtaining a witness or refutation for arbitrary propositions. Then, the incompleteness theorem has essentially the same meaning. Any appropriate formal system will fail to completely characterize the acceptable, 'witnesses,' its proofs may correspond to.

Comment: I think I'm understanding a little better. Godel's theorem shows us that our powers for justification go beyond what is provable in a formal system, but not necessarily that truth goes beyond our powers for justification.

Answer (score 3):

Heyting arithmetic (HA) is the Peano Axioms under constructive logic, while Peano Arithmetic (PA) is Heyting Arithmetic + every instance of excluded middle.

Let's start with the version for an arbitrary potentially constructive theory $T$ with a Godel numbering system that extends HA. Let $\DeclareMathOperator{provable}{provable}$$\provable$ be a provability predicate, phrased as a statement in HA, satisfying the Hilbert-Barnays conditions. Note here that we must constructively prove the meta-thereoretic parts of these three conditions, but for various reasons a classical proof of these three conditions almost always can be translated algorithmically into a constructive proof in practice.

Using the Diagonal Lemma (which is constructive), take some $\phi$ such that $T \vdash \phi \iff \neg \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$. In particular, $T \vdash \phi \to \neg \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$, and thus $T \vdash \provable(\ulcorner \phi \to \neg \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \urcorner)$ by Hilbert-Barnays 1.

Working within $T$:

Suppose that $\provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$. Then $\provable(\ulcorner \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \urcorner)$ by Hilbert-Barnays condition 2.

Also, since we have $\provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$ and $\provable(\ulcorner \phi \to \neg \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \urcorner)$, we have $\provable(\ulcorner \neg \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \urcorner)$.

Recalling that $\neg P$ is "syntactic sugar" for $P \to \bot$. Since we have $\provable(\ulcorner \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \urcorner)$ and $\provable(\ulcorner \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \to \bot \urcorner)$, we again apply Hilbert-Barnays 2 to get $\provable(\ulcorner \bot \urcorner)$.

So we have proved in $T$ that $\provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \to \provable(\ulcorner \bot \urcorner)$. $\square$

In other words, $T$ proves that if $\phi$ is provable, then $T$ is inconsistent. Taking the contrapositive, we see that $T$ proves that if $T$ is consistent, then $\neg \provable(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$. In other words, if $T$ is consistent, then $\phi$.

Now let's say we're working in a metatheory which (1) interprets HA in a canonical way, (2) proves $T$ is consistent, and (3) proves that all HA statements provable in $\phi$ hold in the canonical interpretation of HA. Then this metatheory proves that the HA interpretation of $\phi$ is true.

So there is no constructive problem with dealing with the truth of Godel statements (any more than there is a classical problem).

Note that an alternate tactic is proving that $\provable$ is a Hilbert-Barnays predicate *for HA*. Then as long as $\provable$ actually corresponds to $T$-provability, the proof goes through. This allows us to prove, for instance, the Godel sentence for PA.

Comment: For me this answer hinges on the meaning of condition (1) "interprets HA in a canonical way". This condition corresponds to the classical explanation (of true $\phi$) "interprets PA in the standard model". In the latter case $\phi$ is false in non-standard models. So in HA $\phi$ would be false in "non-canonical intrepetations of HA". But what exactly are these "non-canonical intrepretations" - are they "easily" defined and distinguished from the canonical interpretations?